# Why is Mace4 valuation not working in my Python program?

Tags: python, nltk, inference

Here is a very simple example of the use of Mace4, taken directly from the NLTK Web site:

```
from nltk.sem import Expression
from nltk.inference import MaceCommand

read_expr = Expression.fromstring
a = read_expr('(see(mary,john) & -(mary = john))')
mb = MaceCommand(assumptions=[a])
mb.build_model()
print(mb.valuation)
```

When instead of `mb.valuation` I print the return value of `mb.build_model()` I get `True` so the model is correctly built. But when I ask `print(mb.valuation)`I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(mb.valuation)
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/inference/mace.py", line 51, in valuation
    return mbc.model("valuation")
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/inference/api.py", line 355, in model
    return self._decorate_model(self._model, format)
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/inference/mace.py", line 185, in _decorate_model
    return self._convert2val(valuation_str)
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/inference/mace.py", line 60, in _convert2val
    valuation_standard_format = self._transform_output(valuation_str, "standard")
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/inference/mace.py", line 206, in _transform_output
    return self._call_interpformat(valuation_str, [format])[0]
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/inference/mace.py", line 220, in _call_interpformat
    self._interpformat_bin = self._modelbuilder._find_binary(
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/inference/prover9.py", line 177, in _find_binary
    return nltk.internals.find_binary(
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 675, in find_binary
    return next(
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 661, in find_binary_iter
    yield from find_file_iter(
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 620, in find_file_iter
    raise LookupError(f"\n\n{div}\n{msg}\n{div}")
LookupError: 

===========================================================================
NLTK was unable to find the interpformat file!
Use software specific configuration parameters or set the PROVER9 environment variable.

  Searched in:
    - /usr/local/bin/prover9
    - /usr/local/bin/prover9/bin
    - /usr/local/bin
    - /usr/bin
    - /usr/local/prover9
    - /usr/local/share/prover9

  For more information on interpformat, see:
    <https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/prover9/>
===========================================================================
```

I installed Prover9 through `brew install` and everything went fine. Am I doing something wrong?

========================

Following advice by Grimlock I did a `brew -prefix prover9` which gave me the path `/usr/local/opt/prover9` and tried several methods to communicate it to mace: I added the environment variable `PROVER9` to `.bash_profile`, I included an `os.environ['PROVER9']` to my script and I even added the path to the Python script `prover9.py`. Nothing changed, this path appears in the list of paths but otherwise I still get the error message below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-mace.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(mb.valuation)
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/inference/mace.py", line 51, in valuation
    return mbc.model("valuation")
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/inference/api.py", line 355, in model
    return self._decorate_model(self._model, format)
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/inference/mace.py", line 185, in _decorate_model
    return self._convert2val(valuation_str)
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/inference/mace.py", line 60, in _convert2val
    valuation_standard_format = self._transform_output(valuation_str, "standard")
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/inference/mace.py", line 206, in _transform_output
    return self._call_interpformat(valuation_str, [format])[0]
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/inference/mace.py", line 220, in _call_interpformat
    self._interpformat_bin = self._modelbuilder._find_binary(
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/inference/prover9.py", line 178, in _find_binary
    return nltk.internals.find_binary(
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 675, in find_binary
    return next(
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 661, in find_binary_iter
    yield from find_file_iter(
  File "/Users/yannis/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 620, in find_file_iter
    raise LookupError(f"\n\n{div}\n{msg}\n{div}")
LookupError: 

===========================================================================
NLTK was unable to find the interpformat file!
Use software specific configuration parameters or set the PROVER9 environment variable.

  Searched in:
    - /usr/local/bin/prover9
    - /usr/local/bin/prover9/bin
    - /usr/local/bin
    - /usr/bin
    - /usr/local/prover9
    - /usr/local/share/prover9
    - /usr/local/opt/prover9

  For more information on interpformat, see:
    <https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/prover9/>
===========================================================================
```

Comment: Is Prover correctly installed? check it with `prover9` in console. Another thing is, maybe `interpformat` is not located in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in error, your program is unable to find prover9. To fix that, you must find where it is installed and add it to your path.

Find the installation path by running the following:

```
brew --prefix prover9
```

This should return the path where prover9 was installed (something like /usr/local/Cellar/prover9/).

Now, you need to set the PROVER9 environment variable to this path. You can do this by running the following command. Remember to change the file according to your shell -- `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, or `.zshrc`. Example commands for `bash_profile`:

```
echo 'export PROVER9=<PATH_TO_PROVER9>' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

After adding this line, restart your terminal (or run `source .bashrc`, `source .bash_profile`, or `source .zshrc`) to apply the changes.

Now, run your Python script again, and the error should be resolved.

---- Alternate approach ----

If you still encounter issues, you can also try setting the PROVER9 environment variable directly in your Python script:

```
import os
os.environ['PROVER9'] = '<PATH_TO_PROVER9>'
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I did as you said and got the path `/usr/local/opt/prover9`, I added it to my environment variables and tested it with  `env | grep PROVER9` but the program still produces the same error: `=============================================================NLTK was unable to find the interpformat file!
Use software specific configuration parameters or set the PROVER9 environment variable.

  Searched in:
    - /usr/local/bin/prover9
    - /usr/local/bin/prover9/bin
    - /usr/local/bin
    - /usr/bin
    - /usr/local/prover9
    - /usr/local/share/prover9`

Comment: Are you sure it is the `PROVER9` environment variable that is missing? Because my path does not appear in the list of places where the program is looking.

Comment: @yannis added an alternate approach in the answer. Can you try that?

Comment: It didn't worked. I even went into the `prover9.py`file and added the path to the list of binary locations, now it appears in the list of directories in the error message. But the program still doesn't work.

Comment: Did the error change once you set path in the script itself? 
`os.environ['PROVER9'] = '<PATH_TO_PROVER9>'`
Is the code now looking into opt directory where prover9 is located?

Comment: I updated my original message since in the comments there is not enough place. As you can see nothing changed. The path is in the list because I have put it there.

Comment: Can you try this now and tell me what output it gives? I'm concerned if the library is installed properly. This should give us location of interpformat directly, which the program needs. @yannis

`find "$(brew --prefix prover9)" -name "interpformat"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253361/discussion-between-grimlock-and-yannis).